# Best practice to call an overloaded interface method accepting number and number[] in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, interface, overloading

The situation is next. An overloaded method that accepts `number` and `number[]`

```
interface OverloadInterface {
    accept(x: number): void;
    accept(x: number[]): void;
}
```

What is the best practice to call this method if I have the union type `number|number[]`?

When I try

```
function call(x: number|number[], consumer: OverloadInterface): void{
    consumer.accept(x);
}
```

I get an error ("No overload matches this call") from the transpiler. If I use

```
function call(x: number|number[], consumer: OverloadInterface): void{
    if(Array.isArray(x))
        consumer.accept(x);
    else
        consumer.accept(x);
}
```

the error disappears but the code looks weird.

Comment: I don't know that there is a "best practice" for calling overloads with a union; without [ms/TS#14107](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14107) there are only workarounds.  Personally I'd say that overloads which differ only by the type of one of their arguments shouldn't be overloads at all; you should collapse to a single call signature with the union type.  If you can't, then just do whatever workaround you prefer.... `consumer.accept(x as number)` or the `Array.isArray()` check.  Does that fully address the question? If so I could write up an answer; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Thank you, @jcalz. Yes, you addressed my question.